# ASP.NET Core (.NET 5) + Angular 11 = build error on empty project

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-5

If I create a new ASP.NET Core Web API + Angular project *in Visual Studio* using: `dotnet new angular`, it creates a **.NET 5** project containing in the ClientApp a new **Angular 8.2** project.
If I <kbd>F5</kbd> it, everything works perfectly.

But I want to use and Angular 11 project, so i wipe the ClientApp content, open a terminal there and: `ng new <app-name> --directory ./` there.

Project created, <kbd>F5</kbd>, the project launches but at every launch these 2 lines appear in the Debug Console:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: - Generating browser application bundles...
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: ΓêÜ Browser application bundle generation complete.

I did many attempts: merging values from previous `tsconfig.json`, from `angular.json`, `launchSettings.json`, but nothing solved it.
Instead, if I launch an `ng serve` from the ClientApp directory, it works without errors.

Is there some incompatibility between Visual Studio and Angular's CLI?
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Don't think there are any incompatibilities - but why did you just not upgrade the angular version in the project that was in there? When you created a new one - you lost all .NET integrations that were installed

Comment: So, the application runs despite the console output? If so, ignore those. That is how the SPA services cope with output from the CLI. I see them all the time with the applications where I have done the same thing you did. They are dev/build time messages. They will not effect anything after the application is built and deployed.

Comment: @fredrik: I didn't know there are integrations, I'm pretty new to web development. Anyways, I tried that path 2 times, and even though I follow strictly the official update procedure, the sequence is not straight and there are warnings and errors of modules incompatibilities, if I --force those steps the final project does not work

Comment: @R.Richards: good to know, but it's kinda annoying to have errors and need to ignore them, it creates confusion and may lead to inadvertedly ignore other error notifications, it's ugly and risky

Comment: You can always roll back to the version of the CLI that came with the template.

Answer (score 5):

it is not an actual error. angular writes build progress messages in the stream which dotnet identifies as errors. you can suppress progress (and the *fake* fail messages) adding this key in angular.json:

```
"projects": {
"<PROJECT_NAME>": {
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "progress": false
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I get similar issues and even [asked about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65840557/how-to-investigate-the-reason-of-fail-generating-bundles-for-spa-in-net-core). However, as the replies suggest, it's a matter of Angular producing results that unintentionally look like errors to .NET - basically a case of sloppy coding.

While I recognize your pain and do share it with you, you'll need to accept that MS is a bit behind Angular latest stuff. You should definitely keep going with 11th (or whatever version is the latest), in my opinion.